# Django : Several paths, one ListView, different templates?

Tags: python, django

Please help me. I want to have multiple path in urls.py (lets say a, and b). But I want to ONLY have one ListView, and this ListView need to channel me to different html file when I access the url (a.html when access 'a/', b.html when access 'b/').

Currently I use different ListView for each path (aListView and bListView), even though the model is the same. But it seems that it violate the Don't Repeat Yourself  rule. And the code looks bad.

So the question is how can I define several different templates in one ListView?

Below is my current mind map. Thank you

[My mind route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o0vo.jpg)

Comment: If I got your question correctly, you could create db related stuff in models.py file(having class etc) then in views.py you could have a function which further class it with a name. Now in your application urls.py add 2 entries 1 is for a.html and another for b.html with same function name which we created in views.py. by this you have created only 1 function which is being called by multiple pages(based upon their html template values). Please let me know if this helps you, will make it a complete answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can define multiple paths that points to one ListView within multiple templates:

Let's suppose my app name is `example` and my project name is `test_project`; my setup is like this:

**test_project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    ...,  # my project urls
    path('', include('example.urls'))
]
```

**example/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from example import views

app_name = 'example'
urlpatterns = [
    path('a/', views.GenericListView.as_view(), name='a-url'),
    path('b/', views.GenericListView.as_view(), name='b-url')
]
```

**templates/a.html**

```
This is A file
```

**templates/b.html**

```
This is B file
```

**example/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.urls import reverse


class GenericListView(ListView):
    a_template = 'a.html'
    b_template = 'b.html'

    def get_template_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the request path is the path for a-url in example app
        if self.request.path == reverse('example:a-url'):
            return [self.a_template]  # Return a list that contains "a.html" template name
        return [self.b_template]  # else return "b.html" template name

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        # For this example i'm returning [] as queryset for both a/ and b/ routes
        if self.request.path == reverse('example:a-url'):
            return []  # Return whatever queryset for a/ route
        return []  # Return whatever queryset for b/ route
```

For more informations you can visit [ListView: get_template_names() Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names)

Comment: This is very clear answer and documentation link is helpful too, I was almost doing the same thing but with HttpResponse thing in view.py for showing sample :) will post if I could complete it, cheers and thanks for sharing nice answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks. See my last update for more generic test against your URLs. And don't forget to accept the answer that responds to your question.

Comment: @ChihebNexus greatt. This is what im looking for. It help my day !! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that having 2 separate ListViews is the right approach in your situation. You have 2 different URLs and 2 different templates, so you have 2 different views. I don't think that it violates DRY principles because the common logic is abstracted by the reusable `ListView` class.